# SQLite - Differences between sqlite3_errmsg and sqlite3_errstr

Tags: sqlite

In presence of both result codes 14 and 526 I get the same result, "unable to open database file".

I expected that one of the two functions would return "SQLITE_CANTOPEN" and "SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ISDIR", respectively.

And maybe that the error description would be more precise for code 526 indicating that the specified path is actually a directory.

Is this the expected behavior?

Also, is there any way to obtain the results I expected?

---

References:

https://sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html

https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this as well, so I went through the [SQLite3 source code](https://sqlite.org/download.html) and found that `sqlite3_errmsg` is defined in sqlite3.c at line 180756 and `sqlite3_errstr` is defined in sqlite3.c at line 180867.

TLDR; `sqlite3_errmsg` does more checking on the database connection (`sqlite3*`) and provides more comprehensive error information (including that provided by `sqlite3_errstr`).

---

- `sqlite3_errmsg`:

```c
/*
** Return UTF-8 encoded English language explanation of the most recent
** error.
*/
SQLITE_API const char *sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3 *db){
  const char *z;
  if( !db ){
    return sqlite3ErrStr(SQLITE_NOMEM_BKPT);
  }
  if( !sqlite3SafetyCheckSickOrOk(db) ){
    return sqlite3ErrStr(SQLITE_MISUSE_BKPT);
  }
  sqlite3_mutex_enter(db->mutex);
  if( db->mallocFailed ){
    z = sqlite3ErrStr(SQLITE_NOMEM_BKPT);
  }else{
    testcase( db->pErr==0 );
    z = db->errCode ? (char*)sqlite3_value_text(db->pErr) : 0;
    assert( !db->mallocFailed );
    if( z==0 ){
      z = sqlite3ErrStr(db->errCode);
    }
  }
  sqlite3_mutex_leave(db->mutex);
  return z;
}
```

- `sqlite3_errstr`:

```c
/*
** Return a string that describes the kind of error specified in the
** argument.  For now, this simply calls the internal sqlite3ErrStr()
** function.
*/
SQLITE_API const char *sqlite3_errstr(int rc){
  return sqlite3ErrStr(rc);
}
```